# Why is SortedDictionary<K, V>.GetEnumerator O(log n) but SortedSet<T>.GetEnumerator O(1)?

Tags: .net, big-o, asymptotic-complexity, sortedset, sorteddictionary

From the [`SortedSet<T>.GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382041(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> This method is an O(1) operation

From the [`SortedDictionary<K, V>.GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z8z05h2(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> This method is an O(log n) operation, where n is count.

Can both the statements be true, considering `SortedDictionary<K, V>` is internally implemented as a `SortedSet<KeyValuePair<K, V>`? I checked the `GetEnumerator` code of `SortedDictionary` class - it directly uses the `SortedSet`'s enumerator. I noticed `SortedSet`'s enumerator implementation and it seemed to me it does have O(log n) characteristic (here is the code):

```
public SortedSet<T>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
{
  return new SortedSet<T>.Enumerator(this);
}

//which calls this constructor:
internal Enumerator(SortedSet<T> set)
{
  this.tree = set;
  this.tree.VersionCheck();
  this.version = this.tree.version;
  this.stack = new Stack<SortedSet<T>.Node>(2 * SortedSet<T>.log2(set.Count + 1));
  this.current = (SortedSet<T>.Node) null;
  this.reverse = false;
  this.siInfo = (SerializationInfo) null;
  this.Intialize();
}

private void Intialize()
{
  this.current = (SortedSet<T>.Node) null;
  SortedSet<T>.Node node1 = this.tree.root;
  while (node1 != null)
  {
    SortedSet<T>.Node node2 = this.reverse ? node1.Right : node1.Left;
    SortedSet<T>.Node node3 = this.reverse ? node1.Left : node1.Right;
    if (this.tree.IsWithinRange(node1.Item))
    {
      this.stack.Push(node1);
      node1 = node2;
    }
    else
      node1 = node2 == null || !this.tree.IsWithinRange(node2.Item) ? node3 : node2;
  }
}
```

**Doesn't that mean the documentation is wrong and `SortedSet<T>.GetEnumerator` is O(log n)?** Nothing much about performance of `GetEnumerator` call, just ensuring if I understand correctly.

Comment: Well, that looks like a documentation bug for sure.

Comment: You need to check the code for SortedDictionary to see what's going on.  Does it call SortedSet log(n) times?  If so, the documentation is correct.

Comment: @user2880486 SortedDictionary directly calls the SortedSet enumerator. Since internally it is implemented as `SortedSet<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`. No it doesnt call the enumerator log n times. Furthermore, my problem is not SortedDictionary being O logn, but SortedSet being O 1. Thats why I posted just the code of enumerator of SortedSet. It doesnt seem O 1 but O logn from the code.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback sent about our topic on MSDN. I have fixed the documentation bug in our [latest version of the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382041%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Unfortunately, I can't fix the 4.0 version of the same topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely agree with you.

The `SortedSet` uses the *red black tree* structure internally which is guaranteed to be balanced ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Proof_of_asymptotic_bounds); [Red-Black Trees, R. Sedgewick, Princeton University](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall08/cos226/lectures/10BalancedTrees-2x2.pdf)).
Therefore the height is limited by `2 * log2(n + 1)`. Even a [code comment](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/sortedset.cs,2177) in *SortedSet.cs* points that out and the size of the enumerator's stack is set accordingly.

The `while` loop that prepares the stack is **O(log n)** in both initializing and proceeding (`MoveNext`) the enumerator.

Feedback on the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382041.aspx) referring to this discussion submitted.

### Update:

By today Microsoft finally updated the documentation. For the 4.0 version it still states it's an O(1) operation. Although I doubt it, I can leave it at that.

Comment: By today Microsoft finally updated the documentation. For the 4.0 version it still states it's an O(1) operation. Although I doubt it, I can leave it at that.